# add a commit automatically when I bump version

Tags: git, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

I used to have that behavior be default when I did `npm version patch | minor| major` but it disappeared.

How can I trigger a commit with version change on package.json automatically when I bump the version of my project with npm or yarn?

Comment: Which version of npm are you using? Even with the latest version as of now (6.5.0), `npm version` should auto-commit and tag with the relevant new version. Also, check your `git-tag-version` setting by running `npm config get git-tag-version`. This is set to true by default, but perhaps you've now got it set to false.

Comment: It is set to true. But there is no autocomit on version bump.

Comment: In that case, you could always use a bit of piping magic to accomplish the auto-commit. For example, `npm version patch | xargs -n 1 -I {} git commit -a -m "{}"`. If that's too much to type all the time, you can always alias the command too.